# Align child div of different Height in 2 columns without using Masonary library

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanted to align cards of different heights into 2 columns that wrap into one row from left to right. I have tried things: display as grid and setting grid-template-row to some value and then assigning row spans. But that does not give me full control over the height of cards. I have around 6 divs returned as an array so cannot clearly think how flex box would give me two columns as flex is one dimensional.

My HTML is in the form of:

```
<div className="parent">
    <div className="child-1"></div>
    <div className="child-2"></div>
    <div className="child-3"></div>
    <div className="child-4"></div>
    <div className="child-5"></div>
    <div className="child-6"></div>
</div>
```

[image: The layout]

Comment: you show 6 in picture but only 5 in the supplied HTML

Comment: don't stop at the title of duplicate. what you want to achieve is called *masonry layout* and this doesn't mean you have to use a *masory library*. In the duplicate there is CSS only solutions with no external library

Answer (score 0):

If you're width is static then you can just set the widths of all of the elements to be the same 'with a class' and then with flex wrapping they will all line up in columns. From there you can assign whatever heights you want to each.